# PsQl data dump import

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Psql databasename < file.db is the recommended method to import to a database.
This doesn't work why?

Comment: What (apart from saying "This doesn't work") have **you** done to resolve the issue? Please add this detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are possibly not creating the database before attempting to restore it. From [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html),

> 24.1.1. Restoring the Dump
>
> Text files created by pg_dump are intended to be read in by the psql
>   program. The general command form to restore a dump is
>
> psql dbname < infile where infile is the file output by the pg_dump
>   command. The database dbname will not be created by this command, so
>   you must create it yourself from template0 before executing psql
>   (e.g., with createdb -T template0 dbname). psql supports options
>   similar to pg_dump for specifying the database server to connect to
>   and the user name to use. See the psql reference page for more
>   information.

Note the part which says

> "you must create it yourself from template0 before executing psql
>   (e.g., with createdb -T template0 dbname)".

Comment: I have tried createdb for a new database, this didn't work either. I then used adminiii to create a database then tried to restore to this.

Comment: How did this work out?

Comment: Thank you for your interest, turns out that it is my lack of knowledge and poor documentation is the cause of my problem.

Comment: And you could, perhaps, mark my answer as helpful? :-)

Comment: I have given this a tick; what Windows users need to know is you can fall into the trap of thinking it works in a similar manner to a power shell. Also in the Admin III console you can invoke the command console but it will always want you to choose a database and then you can't operate as PSQL commands the /I seems to be equivalent at that stage. The lack of any confirmation or failure message is a bit disconcerting.